# How can I incorporate a child/parent relationship into a sort function?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to sort an array of event objects by their start date, except that some events have parent objects, and if an event has a parent event it should be appear in start date order with its siblings right after the parent event.

I've trade various permutations of the below code, but I can't seem to get it to sort correctly.

The reason I'm trying to put it into a sort function is because the function is handed to a timeline display that will dynamically add/remove events.

JSFiddle showing my results vs expected results: http://jsfiddle.net/8q0786p5/

```
var toJsDates = function(arr){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i].start = new Date(arr[i].start);
    }
}
var checkOrder = function(arr){
    var output = "<table><tr><th>index</th><th>expected</th><th>got</th></tr>";
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length && i < eventsInCorrectOrder.length;i++){
        output += "<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+eventsInCorrectOrder[i].id+"</td>";

        if(arr[i].id == eventsInCorrectOrder[i].id){
            output += "<td style=\"color:green;\">"+arr[i].id+" - GOOD</td>";
        }
        else{
            output += "<td style=\"color:red;\">"+arr[i].id+" - WRONG</td>";
        }

        output += "</tr>";
    }
    output += "</table>";

    document.body.innerHTML += output;
}

var events = [
    {id: 1,  content: 'item 1', start: '2013-04-20'},
    {id: 2,  content: 'item 2', start: '2013-01-14'},
    {id: 3,  content: 'item 3', start: '2013-04-18'},
    {id: 4,  content: 'item 4', start: '2013-04-16'},
    {id: 5,  content: 'item 5', start: '2013-04-25'},
    {id: 6,  content: 'item 6', start: '2013-09-21'},
    {id: 7,  content: 'item 7', start: '2013-04-23'},
    {id: 8,  content: 'item 8', start: '2013-04-11'},
    {id: 9,  content: 'item 9', start: '2013-04-10'},
    {id: 10, content: 'item 10', start: '2013-04-13'},
    {id: 11, content: 'item 11', start: '2013-04-15'},
    {id: 12, content: 'item 12', start: '2013-08-22'},
    {id: 21, content: 'item 13', start: '2013-06-21'},
    {id: 22, content: 'item 14', start: '2013-04-17'},
    {id: 23, content: 'item 15', start: '2013-04-17'},
    {id: 24, content: 'item 16', start: '2013-04-10'},
    {id: 25, content: 'item 17', start: '2013-04-24'},
    {id: 26, content: 'item 18', start: '2013-04-23'},
    {id: 27, content: 'item 19', start: '2013-04-28'},
    {id: 28, content: 'item 20', start: '2013-04-19'},
    {id: 29, content: 'item 21', start: '2013-04-05'},
    {id: 42, content: 'A Project', start: '2013-04-23'},
    {id: 43, content: 'Initial Mtg',  start: '2013-04-24', parentId: 42},
    {id: 44, content: 'Mid-term Mtg', start: '2013-04-28', parentId: 42},
    {id: 45, content: 'Final Mtg',    start: '2013-05-09', parentId: 42},
    {id: 46, content: 'B Project', start: '2013-04-23'},
    {id: 47, content: 'IPC', start: '2013-04-23', parentId: 46},
    {id: 48, content: 'MPC', start: '2013-04-25', parentId: 46},
    {id: 49, content: 'FPC', start: '2013-05-02', parentId: 46},
    {id: 50, content: 'Standalone Meeting', start: '2013-04-23'},
];

var getEventById = function(id){
    for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++){
        if(events[i].id == i) return events[i];
    }
    return false;
}

var eventsInCorrectOrder = [
    {id: 2,  content: 'item 2', start: '2013-01-14'},
    {id: 29, content: 'item 21', start: '2013-04-05'},
    {id: 9,  content: 'item 9', start: '2013-04-10'},
    {id: 24, content: 'item 16', start: '2013-04-10'},
    {id: 8,  content: 'item 8', start: '2013-04-11'},
    {id: 10, content: 'item 10', start: '2013-04-13'},
    {id: 11, content: 'item 11', start: '2013-04-15'},
    {id: 4,  content: 'item 4', start: '2013-04-16'},
    {id: 22, content: 'item 14', start: '2013-04-17'},
    {id: 23, content: 'item 15', start: '2013-04-17'},
    {id: 3,  content: 'item 3', start: '2013-04-18'},
    {id: 28, content: 'item 20', start: '2013-04-19'},
    {id: 1,  content: 'item 1', start: '2013-04-20'},
    {id: 21, content: 'item 13', start: '2013-06-21'},
    {id: 12, content: 'item 12', start: '2013-08-22'},
    {id: 7,  content: 'item 7', start: '2013-04-23'},
    {id: 26, content: 'item 18', start: '2013-04-23'},
    {id: 42, content: 'A Project', start: '2013-04-23'},
    {id: 43, content: 'Initial Mtg',  start: '2013-04-24', parentId: 42},
    {id: 44, content: 'Mid-term Mtg', start: '2013-04-28', parentId: 42},
    {id: 45, content: 'Final Mtg',    start: '2013-05-09', parentId: 42},
    {id: 46, content: 'B Project', start: '2013-04-23'},
    {id: 47, content: 'IPC', start: '2013-04-23', parentId: 46},
    {id: 50, content: 'Standalone Meeting', start: '2013-04-23'},
    {id: 25, content: 'item 17', start: '2013-04-24'},
    {id: 5,  content: 'item 5', start: '2013-04-25'},
    {id: 27, content: 'item 19', start: '2013-04-28'},
    {id: 48, content: 'MPC', start: '2013-04-25', parentId: 46},
    {id: 49, content: 'FPC', start: '2013-05-02', parentId: 46},
    {id: 6,  content: 'item 6', start: '2013-09-21'}
];

// Normally this is handled elsewhere, just for demonstration purposes
toJsDates(events);
toJsDates(eventsInCorrectOrder);

// Test the events for correctness
document.body.innerHTML += "<h1>Unsorted events</h1>";
checkOrder(events);

// Sort function to use
var sortEventsFunc = function(a,b){   
    var ap,bp;

    // Both have a parent
    if(a.parentId && b.parentId){
        ap = getEventById(a.parentId);
        bp = getEventById(b.parentId);

        // Different parents
        if(ap.id != bp.id){
            a = ap;
            b = bp;
        }
    }
    // A has a parent
    else if(a.parentId){
        ap = getEventById(a.parentId);

        if(b.id == ap.parentId){
            return 1; // favor b
        }

        a = ap;
    }
    // B has a parent
    else  if(b.parentId){
        bp = getEventById(b.parentId);

        if(a.id == bp.parentId){
            return -1; // favor a
        }

        b = bp;
    }

    var dateDiff = b.start - a.start;

    if(dateDiff == 0){
        return b.id - a.id;
    }

    return dateDiff;
}

// Sort the events and try again
events = events.sort(sortEventsFunc);
document.body.innerHTML += "<h1>Sorted events</h1>";
checkOrder(events);

// Verify the checkOrder function
document.body.innerHTML += "<h1>Pre-sorted events to verify</h1>";
checkOrder(eventsInCorrectOrder);
```

Comment: You can sort all items regardless of their parents. After that sort, cycle through the times again and group them by id. I can help you with code later.

Comment: It is dangerous to look if values exist like you do, e.g.: `var id = 0; if (id) { /* won't be reached */ }`

Comment: That's expected behavior; not all events have parents.

Comment: I've added my solution and it seems to be working per your expected results just where are two elements with the same start  date it shows different results.

Comment: Is my solution not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the most efficient way, so it is a good solution if you don't have a lot of events.

The JS without the object:

```
 var newEvents = [];
 var childEvents = [];
 var parentEvents = [];

 $.each(events, function (i, e) {
     e.start = new Date(e.start);
     if (e.end) {
         e.end = new Date(e.end);
     }
 });

 events.sort(function (a, b) {
     return a.start - b.start;
 });

 $.each(events, function (i, e) {
     if (e.parentId) {
         childEvents.push(e);
     } else {
         parentEvents.push(e);
     }
 });

 $.each(parentEvents, function (i, e) {
     newEvents.push(e);
     $.each(childEvents, function (childIndex, child) {
         if (child.parentId == e.id) {
             newEvents.push(child);
         }
     });
 });


 $.each(newEvents, function (i, e) {
     console.log(e.content);
 });
```

[Fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/c3Lwsu32/7/)

Another approach you can add relationship to the way the object is build- you can create the child events as a property of the parent, and then you can sort Parent/children:

```
var addRelationships = function(){
    $.each(events,function(i,e){
        if(e.parentId){
            for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++){
                var parent = events[i];

                if(parent.id == e.parentId){
                    e.parent = parent;
                }

                if(!parent.children){
                    parent.children = [e];
                }
                else{
                    parent.children.push(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
}

events.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.children && $.inArray(b, a.children)){// b is a's child
        return -1;//favor parent a
    }
    else if(b.children && $.inArray(a, b.children)){// a is b's child
        return 1;//favor parent b
    }
    if(a.parent && b.parent){//both have parent
        if(a.parent.id == b.parent.id){//same parent
            return a.start - b.start;// standard sorting
        }
        else{
            return a.parent.start - b.parent.start;// sort by parent
        }
    }
    else if(a.parent){
        a = a.parent;
    }
    else if(b.parent){
        b = b.parent;
    }

    return a.start - b.start;
});
```

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution that is contained in a sort function, so that I wont have to inject resorting into the application when items are updated.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to achieve this with sort function the way it is built now. If you can build it that every parents holds a property of the same type of event - "childEvent", then maybe you can do it by sorting the parents, and sorting inside each parents, its 'children'.

Comment: Good call! That's exactly what was needed. Maybe you can append your answer with the working sorting function: http://pastie.org/pastes/10202946/text

Answer (score 1):

```
events = mergeSort(events, ['group', 'id']);

function mergeSort(objArr, props, direction, start, end) {
  var tmp;
  if (typeof start == 'undefined') {
    start = 0;
  }
  if (typeof end == 'undefined') {
    end = objArr.length - 1;
  }
  if (typeof direction == 'undefined' || direction >= 0) {
    direction = 1; // asc
  } else {
    direction = -1; // desc
  }
  tmp = end - start;
  if (tmp == 0) {
    return [objArr[start]];
  } else if (tmp == 1) {
    if (compare(objArr[start], objArr[end], props) * direction > 0) {
      return [objArr[end], objArr[start]];
    } else {
      return [objArr[start], objArr[end]];
    }
  } else if (tmp >= 2) {
    tmp = Math.floor(start + tmp / 2);
    var t1 = mergeSort(objArr, props, direction, start, tmp);
    var t2 = mergeSort(objArr, props, direction, tmp + 1, end);
    var ret = [];
    var c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
    for (;;) {
      if (compare(t1[c1], t2[c2], props) * direction > 0) {
        ret.push(t2[c2]);
        if (++c2 == t2.length) {
          for (tmp = c1; tmp < t1.length; tmp++) {
            ret.push(t1[tmp]);
          }
          break;
        }
      } else {
        ret.push(t1[c1]);
        if (++c1 == t1.length) {
          for (tmp = c2; tmp < t2.length; tmp++) {
            ret.push(t2[tmp]);
          }
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
  return [];
}

function compare(a, b, props) {
  for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    if (typeof a[props[i]] == 'undefined') {
      if (typeof b[props[i]] == 'undefined') {
        continue;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    } else if (typeof b[props[i]] == 'undefined') {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a[props[i]] < b[props[i]]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a[props[i]] > b[props[i]]) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddtwxa6p/

**Plan B**

```
events.sort(function(a, b) {
  var props = ['group', 'id'];
  for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    if (a[props[i]] < b[props[i]]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a[props[i]] > b[props[i]]) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
});
```

**"Group By"**

```
events = groupBy(events, 'id', 'parentId');

function groupBy(objArr, id, parentId) {
  var i,j, parents = [], pids = {};
  for (i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof objArr[i][parentId] != 'undefined') {
      if (typeof pids[objArr[i][parentId]] == 'undefined') {
        pids[objArr[i][parentId]] = [];
      }
      pids[objArr[i][parentId]].push(i);
    } else {
      parents.push(objArr[i]);
    }
  }
  var ret = [];
  for (i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    ret.push(parents[i]);
    if (typeof pids[parents[i][id]] == 'undefined') { continue;}
    for (j = 0; j < pids[parents[i][id]].length; j++) {
      ret.push(objArr[pids[parents[i][id]][j]]);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddtwxa6p/3/

Before creating the output you can sort the parents (same for the children in each group). If there are children with invalid parentIds then they are ignored. Because the algorithm is **stable** you can also just sort the objArray in advance (i.e. by id) and then everything should be as you want without any additional sorting.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/cd0bn08x/ -- also if possible I'd prefer to use a sort function since it's passed as a config parameter

Comment: @Bob just forgot Math.floor... corrected and also added jsfiddle

Comment: @Bob about the other request: you can just plug in the compare function at the bottom into the sort function

Comment: Ah I see. This is sorting by id and group though. I suppose it does happen to work with the example dataset, but I can't assume the IDs will always line up and I want to sort by start and parentId.

Comment: @Bob the ids don't have to line up it is actually obj['xyz'] which is the same as obj.xyz - you just need to specify the properties after which you want to sort in order, however this is only for numbers, might have to add some lines for strings

Comment: But even changing the properties to for example ['start','parentId'] wont sort the events correctly, it's not a "ID ASC, GROUP ASC" kind of sort it has to take into account that child events need to stay just below their parents.

Comment: @Bob added the handling of missing properties to compare, should work for parentId too, undefined is considered to be the biggest value. Then I think you don't want to sort you want to group by parentId? It works http://jsfiddle.net/ddtwxa6p/1/

Comment: @Bob correction: undefined is considered to be the smallest value

Comment: The sort order is not correct -- I'll add the expected sort order to the question to clarify

Comment: @Bob it's alright I understand now what you want, but like I said: the sorting is working correctly, what you want is more like a group by

Comment: @Bob were looking too far. You can sort in advance using the mergeSort (e.g. by id) and afterwards you call groupBy and you will get the correct output because my grouping algorithm is stable (doesn't change order if not needed). See updated answer at the bottom.